# How to assign NSData from within NSOperationQueue to NSData from outside the NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, json, xcode, nsoperationqueue

I need to download data from a JSON, and assign the data to an `NSData` outside the `NSOperationQueue`. Here is my code:

```
-(void)parsingInfo {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someJSON.json"];
    NSData *data;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] queue:downloadQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* jsonData, NSError* error){

        if(error)
        {
            // Error Downloading data
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
        else
        {
            data = jsonData;
        }
    }];

    if (data) {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *JSONDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        application = [JSONDic objectForKey:@"Applications"];
        NSArray *featured = [JSONDic objectForKey:@"Featured"];
        NSDictionary *dict2;
        dict2 = [featured objectAtIndex:0];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Error, no data!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `if(data)` part of the code to inside the NSOperation queue.  Basically your function will fire a new thread to run the download then will immediately continue to check if data exists (probably before the download even starts).

Comment: ok, but then the array application will be nil

Comment: Ok, then when the asynchronous request finishes, fire into the main thread with a new function that knows what the array `application` is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to wait for 'data' to be filled before reaching to 'if (data)' statement then either..
a) Make synchronousRequest call.

```
  + (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
```

OR,

b) user semaphores to block/interrupt this thread until you receive data.

```
-(void)parsingInfo
{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@http://someJSON.json];
            __block NSData *data;

                // Create a semaphore to block this thread ( or run loop) until we get response back from server.
            dispatch_semaphore_t waitSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] queue:downloadQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* jsonData, NSError* error){

                if(error)
                {
                    // Error Downloading data
                    NSLog(@"Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    data = jsonData;
                }

               // Signal to release the semaphore (i.e. unblock the current thread).
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(waitSemaphore);

            }];
                // A dispatch semaphore is an efficient implementation of a traditional counting semaphore. Dispatch semaphores call down
            // to the kernel only when the calling thread needs to be blocked. If the calling semaphore does not need to block, no kernel call is made.
            while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(waitSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
            {
                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
            }

            // Release the semaphore.
            dispatch_release(waitSemaphore);

            if (data) {
                NSError *error;
                NSDictionary *JSONDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

                application = [JSONDic objectForKey:@"Applications"];
                NSArray *featured = [JSONDic objectForKey:@"Featured"];
                NSDictionary *dict2;
                dict2 = [featured objectAtIndex:0];

            } else {

                NSLog(@"Error, no data!");
            }
```

}

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thanks, it is super quick now, but you should replace NSData *data; with __block NSData *data;

Comment: Why negative vote? It's an accepted answer and I have used this solution in one of my project.

Comment: Do not use synchronous networking/blocking threads in iOS.  There's no need for it and it's a poor design.  You can do everything with blocks or delegates in a much more cpu/UI-friendly way.  Not to mention simpler.

Comment: @jsd - I agree with intent of your statement:- NOT blocking UI (main thread). But, if you are making data fetch request already on another thread (say, meant for some data fetch purpose) then semaphore approach is appropriate based on your design / purpose of current thread. The original question doesn't mention about 'main' thread, so my answer/suggestion stands valid for the issue user faced. Hope I convinced you :)

Comment: OK, I tested it now, and it isnt that quick, do you have any other methode?

Answer (score 2):

Pass a block into your NSOperation that the operation can call with the NSData object as a parameter.

Comment: Do you mean __block NSData *data?

Comment: No, you only need that if you're going to modify data in the block.  You just want the operation to pass the data back to the block.